# Storing Projects on Google Drive (Cloud)

Tags: cloud-computing, storage, backups

I've started using Google Drive for my cloud needs and backing up pretty much everything. I've got the app installed so it auto-sync's all my content in most things.

My question is this, I am currently coding for iOS (although this applies to any coding project) and am split on storing my project files on Google Drive while using sync. My theory is that if I did use it, I'd never have to worry about system crashes or lost code before backups, but if I do use it it will be sync'ing a-lot and I thought there might be problems with it detecting changes and trying to sync for example half way through compiling.

Bandwidth isn't an issue as I have fast connection and unlimited monthly allowance.

Has anyone ever used this, or similar cloud-based sync'ing (dropbox etc) for this and knows whether it works or not or whether there are any potential problems etc.

Comment: Hi James, is there a reason you don't use an online source repository ? For code, it looks to me that is much more indicated than Google Drive. I personally use https://bitbucket.org for my pet projects and I commit every few minutes.

Comment: Bitbucket or git was going to be my alternative I was only wondering about Google Drive as that would keep all my files, source code to photos, under one roof

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Cloud-based file syncing is great for pictures of your cat.

Cloud-based scm such as [github](http://github.com) or [bitbucket](http://bitbucket.org) are what you should use for code. They have all the advantages of cloud file storage plus nearly magical abilities to version, compare and merge source files.

Personally I'm partial to bitbucket as you get [free unlimited private and public repositories](https://bitbucket.org/plans)  and mercurial is much more approachable than git.