# Combine auto-syncing cloud and VCS

Tags: version-control, cloud-computing, storage, backups

This [question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/164726/storing-projects-on-google-drive-cloud) brought me to another question: **is there any VCS/tool for a VCS which automatically backups your source code between the last checkout and current changes**?

I had the problem of loosing uncommited source code changes just one week ago.
I did not want to commit yet because the changes were incomplete. But then, an error when moving the data to an USB stick caused the data loss.

That's the opposite what a cloud service (like Google Drive, SkyDrive, DropBox, ...) does: it tracks **each** change you made!

Have you lost your data? That's no problem because you have the latest version online.

So what would a combined solution look like?

It would offer full functionality of a VCS including auto-syncing of any **intermediate changes** between two commits/checkouts to a temporary online location.

Comment: Store your local branch in Dropbox/equivalent. Make as many commits as you want to on your local branch then push to the master branch when your ready.

Comment: @Joel - The only problem would be to avoid syncing until the VCS metadata is in a consistent state.

Comment: Another problem is that all cloud storage providers only allow one folder for all data. And I do not want to store separate projects there and the others on my other partition.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what VCS you are using, but if it's a DCVS like git or Mercurial, you can simply commit along the way, even un finished/unstable edits, then rewrite history (through `git rebase` or the mercurial equivalent), before pushing.

That's one of the main interest of DCVS